# Android: resizing a surface from a surfaceview

Tags: android, resize, android-camera, surfaceview

I was using a tutorial for camera2 api for android and one of the steps was to resize the textureview's surface to an acceptable format by doing the following:

```
 SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
 surfaceTecture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight();
 Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
 previewBuilder = CD.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
 previewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
```

So the mPreviewSize variable is of type Size and it was determined beforehand it cycles through the acceptable formats and selects the most optimal one according to your screen size. The problem is I'm using a SurfaceView and I'm trying to resize the surface object in the SurfaceView I tried this but it didn't work:

```
            SurfaceHolder SH= gameSurface.getHolder();
            SH.setFixedSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface Sur = SH.getSurface();
            previewBuilder = CD.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            previewBuilder.addTarget(Sur);
```

So in debug mode I see mPreviewSize is correct (as in it is set to an acceptable format) but I get an error saying that I'm trying to use an unacceptable format size, it shows the size and it's not the same as mPreviewSize which means the resizing isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: `setFixedSize()` only applies to rendering with Canvas or GLES. When you send images from Camera to SurfaceView, the size of the Surface will be equal to the size of the frame received. What are you trying to do?

Comment: For camera2, the camera obeys the size set on the SurfaceView (modulo rounding it to one of the sizes supported by the camera). So setFixedSize is generally needed if the nearest-rounding match isn't suitable for the app's purposes.

Comment: @EddyTalvala: shiny!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wait to receive the surfaceChanged callback from the SurfaceView, before trying to use the Surface to create a camera capture session.

setFixedSize doesn't necessarily take effect immediately.

Comment: So in other words, once I calculate best preview size I should set it to the surface size. Then in the onChange method for the srufaceview callback I can flag that now the surface is ready to use and then I can call camera session at that very moment. Is that what you're saying? I will try this anyways.